# "Demonstrate Block Regions" not showing

Tags: blocks, theming

I did a minimal install, with a desire to get rid of some of the stuff my site-to-be won't need.

The problem I have... is I can't seem to get Demonstrate Block Regions working. It shows up on a "Standard" install... but not the "Minimal" install on 7.

Top one is Standard install. Bottom one is Minimal.
[image]

What module or setting am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the System help block.

That is what is displaying the current help tips:

[SS http://tardis1.tinygrab.com/grabs/99f4a5fef70efc8f19ddb137c664c7cf22b0599ff5.jpg](http://tardis1.tinygrab.com/grabs/99f4a5fef70efc8f19ddb137c664c7cf22b0599ff5.jpg)

When you activate the block the help tips will be displayed whenever possible.

Comment: Disabled help, advanced help. "Uninstalled". Enabled help. No Demonstrate Regions. Enabled advanced help. Still no Demonstrate Regions. I know WHAT it is... that's why I want it back :(

Comment: Help module was installed... but it wasn't set within the "Administration theme" => "Help region".

Comment: @WernerCD My mistake, updated answer with correct solution.

Comment: Make sure that the administrative theme (usually "seven") is enabled (on admin/appearance). If it's set as the admin theme it will work, but if still not enabled, it prevents the help block from being properly configured. THEN place the help block in the help region on the seven theme.